# Are certificates from all Active Directory domain controllers needed on client for LDAPS?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am setting up LDAPS on our AD servers to encrypt ldap authentication between the domain and a web server using an internal CA cert.  The AD servers and web server are on one side of the firewall but the CA is not.  We have two AD servers for redundancy.  Do I have to install certs from both AD servers on to the web server in order to encrypt the LDAPS from end-to-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the specifics of the web server software. That's what this really depends on.

If the web server software isn't validating the certificates used for LDAPS against a CA root certificate then you don't need to do anything. That defeats the purpose of using LDAPS to some extent (since you're opening yourself up to MiTM attacks) so it makes sense to install your CA root certificate as a trusted root on the web server. How you do that, specifically, depends on the web server OS and software.

If the web server is a Windows Server machine that's a member of the Active Directory domain for which your internal CA is acting as an Enterprise root then this trust will be automatic.

It's not necessary to install any certificates from the DCs themselves since those certificates are, presumably, signed by your CA root (which should be trusted by the web server as per the above).

Answer (score 1):

No, the internal CA's root cert should be trusted by the LDAPS client, not the individual entity certificates for the domain controllers.

This trust is automatic in a default configuration, assuming that the web server's a member of that domain.